# Problems with validators in django models

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I want to create an edit page where the customer can edit the profile page. I have a problem with the validators and I don't know how to solve this.

**model.py**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
CAT_G = (
        ('W', 'W'),
        ('M', 'M'),
        ('do not want to mention', 'do not want to mention'),
    )
    age = models.IntegerField(default=1, validators=[ MaxValueValidator(100), MinValueValidator(1)])
    height = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, validators=[MinValueValidator(Decimal('0.0'))], decimal_places=2)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=27, blank=False, null= False, choices=CAT_G)
```

**view.py**

```
def edit_view(request):
    context={}
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = ProfileUpForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.userprofile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/profPage')
    else:
        form = ProfileUpForm(
            initial={
                "age":request.user.userprofile.age,
                "height":request.user.userprofile.height,
                "gender":request.user.userprofile.gender,
            }
        )

        context['profE_form']= form
        return render(request, 'editPage.html', context)
```

**forms.py**

```
class ProfileUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= UserProfile
        fields =('age', 'height', 'gender', )

    def clean_age(self):
        if self.is_valid():
            age=self.cleaned_data['age']
            return age
    
    def clean_height(self):
        if self.is_valid():
            height=self.cleaned_data['height']
            return height
   
    def clean_gender(self):
        if self.is_valid():
            gender=self.cleaned_data['gender']
            return gender
```

**editPage.html**

```
{% for fieldProfile in profE_form %}
            <p>
                {{fieldProfile.label_tag}}
                {{fieldProfile}}
            </p>
            {% endfor %}
```

The problem is that in the html page, the user can choose a negative number, even if I put that validators in my model.
[image]

Comment: Share your `ProfileUpForm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to *render* the errors of the fields, so:

```
{{ profE_form.non_field_errors }}
{% for fieldProfile in profE_form %}
<p>
    {{ fieldProfile.errors }}
    {{ fieldProfile.label_tag }}
    {{ fieldProfile }}
</p>
{% endfor %}
```

You should also render the `profE_form.non_field_errors`. For more information, see the [*Rendering fields manually* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually).

You should not implement the `.clean_…()` methods, and definitely *not* where you call `is_valid()` since Django calls these `.clean_…()` to check if the form is valid.

You can specify the `min` and/or `max` by specifying the widget:

```
from django.forms.widgets import NumberInput

class ProfileUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= UserProfile
        fields = ('age', 'height', 'gender', )
        widgets = {
            'age': NumberInput(attrs=dict(min=1, max=100)),
            'height': NumberInput(attrs=dict(min=0))
        }
```

You can simplify the view by passing the instance to the form with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def edit_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfileUpForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.userprofile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/profPage')
    else:
        form = ProfileUpForm(instance=request.user.userprofile)

    context = {'profE_form': form}
    return render(request, 'editPage.html', context)
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).

Comment: Now, I can see the message errors on my page, "Ensure this value is greater than or equal to 1.
Ensure this value is greater than or equal to 0.0.". But how can I do to restrict the  values from the html page? To only be able to choose positive numbers?

Comment: @AndreeaA: you specify that with the `attrs` of the `widgets`.